# seq() with changing increment of sequence

Tags: r, increment, seq

Let's say I want to create a sequence with base R's `seq()` from 1 to 15. Is there a way that an increment of 1 applies for the values 1 to 10 and 12 to 15 but an increment of .1 applies from 10.1 to 11.9? Basically, I'm interested in how to combine the three sequences `seq(1,10,1)`, `seq(10.1,11.9,0.1)`, `seq(12,15,0.1)` into one `seq()`

Comment: But the answer to his question is "no", you cannot get threel sequences in one `seq` call without packing the arguments into a matrix and using `apply`. Much less typing is `c(seq(1, 9, 1),  seq(10, 12, .1), seq(13, 15, 1))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the idea is just to get a compact expression then try any of these.  s5, in particular, seems close to what you are looking for, viz. a vectorized seq. No packages are used.

```
s1 <- c(1:10, 101:119 / 10, 12:15 )

s2 <- cumsum(rep(c(1, 0.1, 1), c(10, 20, 3)))

s3 <- unlist(Map(seq, c(1, 10.1, 12), c(10, 11.9, 15), c(1, 0.1, 1)))

s4 <- Filter(function(x) (x %% 10 == 0) | (x > 100 & x < 120), 10:150) / 10

s5 <- sequence(nvec = c(10, 20, 3), from = c(10, 101, 130), by = c(10, 1, 10)) / 10

# check
all.equal(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pmap` function from package `purrr` as you would like to iterate over 3 vectors in parallel:

```
library(purrr)

from = c(1, 12, 10.1)
to = c(10, 15, 11.9)
by = c(1, 1, 0.1)

# Then we wrap all three vectors in a list to be able to use pmap
pmap(list(c(1, 12, 10.1), c(10, 15, 11.9), c(1, 1, 0.1)), seq)

[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 12 13 14 15

[[3]]
 [1] 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.0 11.1 11.2 11.3 11.4 11.5 11.6 11.7 11.8
[19] 11.9
```

Comment: However as @markus mentioned your description doesn't match your vectors, so you can modify my code.

Comment: Put the last command in `unlist(pmap . . .)` and you get a single vector.

Comment: why not simply use `mapply( seq, from, to, by)` jn this example?

Comment: I have a tendency toward `purrr` package, however there are other ways of dealing with this problem. It's just a matter of choice.